# Use a loop to add markers on leaflet map from different data frames in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

I am using a checkbox in r shiny to choose the locations plotted from different data sets (eg: playground, libraries, parks). Since the lat and long are present in different data sets, I thought I could use a for loop to update the base leaflet map depending on the check boxes selected. However, I haven't had much success with this as the map just doesn't appear. I get no error either. I am attaching the code snippets as well. If anyone can help me with this, it would be very helpful. If anyone could suggest another method to get things done, I would appreciate it.

###################ui

```
 tabPanel("Other out-of-school resources",
                        fluidPage(sidebarLayout(

                          sidebarPanel(

                            selectInput("neighborhoods_other", "Select the neighborhood from the dataset", choices = c("No neighborhood selected", neighborhoods_other)),
                            br(),
                            checkboxGroupInput("program_other", "Select the type of the program", choices = c("Parks", "Playgrounds", "Rec Centers", "Libraries", 
                                                                                                        "Museums", "Fields"), selected = "Parks"),
                            br(),
                            radioButtons("demographics_other", "Select the demographics variable", choices = c("Median household income ($)","High school degree or equivalent(%)",
                                                                                                         "Hispanic population (%)", "Non native English speakers (%)"), selected = character(0)),
                            br()
                          ),



                          mainPanel(
                            tabsetPanel(type = "tab",
                                        tabPanel("Map",
                                                 leafletOutput("mymap_other", height = 650)),
                                        tabPanel("Data",
                                                 DT::dataTableOutput("datatable_other")),
                                        tabPanel("Summary analysis")
                            )
                          ))
                        )
                        )
```

###########server

```
 colm_other = reactive({

  input$program_other

})


  parks_data = reactive({


    if(input$neighborhoods_other != "No neighborhood selected" ) {

      a = parks[which(parks[, "nbhd_name"] == input$neighborhoods_other),]

    }

    else {

      a = parks

    }

    return(a) 
})


libraries_data = reactive({


  if(input$neighborhoods_other != "No neighborhood selected" ) {

    a = libraries[which(libraries[, "nbhd_name"] == input$neighborhoods_other),]

  }

  else {

    a = libraries

  }

  return(a) 
})






  output$mymap_other = renderLeaflet({



    parks_data1 = parks_data()
    libraries_data1 = libraries_data()

    m = leaflet()  %>% setView(lng = -104.991531, lat = 39.742043,zoom = 10) %>% addTiles()


    for (col in colm_other()){
     if(col == "Parks"){
       print(head(parks_data1))

       map <- m %>% addMarkers(map = m, lng = jitter(parks_data1$long), lat = jitter(parks_data1$lat))


     }

      if(col == "Libraries"){
        print(col)

        map %>% addMarkers(map, lng = jitter(libraries_data1$long), lat = jitter(libraries_data1$lat))


      }

    }
```

Comment: consider explaining your problem statement in further detail

Comment: I have 4 different data sets with the locations of libraries, parks, playgrounds and museums. I want to have a checkbox which enables me to plot the locations of one or any combination of these resources on a leaflet map. The input variables in the checkboxes are the names of the data sets. I have created a loop where i want the map to be updated depending on the input data sets selected in the checkboxes (the last few lines of the code). However, i dont see a map in the app. Neither do i get an error.  Is there a different way to update a leaflet in a loop?

Comment: Or is there any other way i can solve this problem?

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example so people can test your code.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({

# create map

    themap<- leaflet(data = dataset
              ,options = leafletOptions(preferCanvas = TRUE) )  %>%
        addTiles(options = providerTileOptions(
          updateWhenZooming = FALSE,
          updateWhenIdle = FALSE)
        ) %>% setView(lng = median(dataset$lng)
                      ,lat = median(dataset$lat)
                      ,zoom = 9
        )

# add a number of layes to the map in a for loop

    for (service in unique(dataset$service_type) ){
    themap<-addCircleMarkers(map=themap
                             ,data = dataset[which(dataset$service_type %in% service),]
                               ,~lng
                               ,~lat
                               ,clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
                                 iconCreateFunction= JSfunction
                                 ,spiderfyOnMaxZoom = TRUE
                               )
                               , fillColor   = ~pal(service_type)
                               , stroke      = FALSE
                               , fillOpacity = 0.7
        ) # aCM
    } # for
    themap

    })
```